# Duplicate instances of remote service

Tags: android, sockets, service

I have a strange issue, that suddenly happen on some of the android devices on which I'm testing my code.

I'm working with a system composed by multiple activities that share the same remote service used to manage the communication within the entire system.

The problem is that sometimes on some device I get a duplicate instance of the remote service, this could be not a problem, but indeed it is a big problem. In fact as I said the remote service is used to manage the exchange of messages via UDP or TCP, and when I get multiple instance of this service I have problem with sockets, because both the services try to use the same port (broadcast port) resulting in a EADDRINUSE exception.

Someone could explain me why I get multiple instance of this service?

Here is the code where i set the bind to the remote service in my main activity that is inherited by all my activities:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startService(new Intent(
            MyAction.REMOTE_SERVICE_LOAD));

    getApplicationContext().bindService(
            new Intent(IRemoteService.class.getName()), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}

/** The primary interface we will be calling on the service. */
private IRemoteService mService = null;

private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(final ComponentName className,
            final IBinder service) {

        mService = IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        try {
            mService.registerCallback(mCallback);

                launchTask();

        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
        if (mConnection != null && mService != null) {
            mService.unregisterCallback(mCallback);
            getApplicationContext().unbindService(mConnection);
            Log.d(tag, "UNREGISTER SERVICE CALLBACK for activity "
                    + getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//method that will be called when I get a notification on serverUp and i come from
//a serverDown situation

public void notifyConnectionUp() {
    if (!serverConnected) {

        if (mConnection != null) {
            try {
                mService.unregisterCallback(mCallback);
            } catch (final RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getApplicationContext().unbindService(mConnection);

        }

        getApplicationContext().bindService(
                new Intent(IRemoteService.class.getName()), mConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        System.gc();

    }
}
```

The code in my remote service is this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
        final int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {

    if (IRemoteService.class.getName().equals(intent.getAction())) {
        return mBinder;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(tag, "onCreate...RemoteService");

    //Here I have the registration of some receivers and the launch of other services

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    mCallbacks.kill();

}
```

As asked by CommonsWare this is the  tag on my service application:

```
     <service
        android:name="shared.RemoteService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="shared.IRemoteService"/>

            <action
                android:name="shared.REMOTE_SERVICE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Another question, is it correct that when I launch a new activity I always see a call to the method onStartCommand of the service? I was expecting a call to the onBind() method of the service (considering that in my mainActivity I have a call to startService() followed by a call to bindService).

I see that I have multiple instances of my remote service because when I run PS command on my device I get the following result:

D/Command (14049): ID: 1, u0_a67    14013 2330  478116 28620 ffffffff 40767ce8 R service.net:remote
D/Command (14049): ID: 1, u0_a67    31493 14013 477100 21416 00000000 40051a58 R service.net:remote

And as you can see it seems that one service is parent of the other (the second service PPID is 14013 which is the first service PID).

I hope that I have been clear.

Comment: Please post the `<service>` element of your manifest. Also, please use a better test than **`ps`** to determine if you have multiple instances of your service, such as `Log` statements in the service code. You have demonstrated that you have multiple *processes*, which is not the same thing as having multiple *service instances*.

Comment: I edited my question with the manifest section. In the code I posted I removed the log statement, but my code is full of log. Unfortunately with logcat I can't see the instantiation of the second service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you are seeing is the second process, courtesy of `android:process=":remote"`, containing your remote service, and that you only have one instance of the remote service.

You might consider removing `android:process=":remote"`, both temporarily to run a test and confirm this theory, and permanently (unless there is a clear reason why you need to consume more of the user's RAM).

Comment: A question, removing the :remote definition will allow different activity to bind to the same service (or the only difference is that the service is running in a separated process)? I supposed that this definition was necessary to have a single instance of the service shared by different activities. Anyway I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @axlcoder: "I supposed that this definition was necessary to have a single instance of the service shared by different activities." -- no, you do not need `android:process` to have a service that is accessible from other apps.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!! You've solved a problem that haunted me for a long time, and led to a bad behavior of the entire system. I'd offer you a happy dinner in addition to the classic beer;)